# Ubuntu 14.10 doesn't boot after update from 14.04

Tags: boot, 14.10

first i got to say, i'm a complete newbie to ubuntu/linux.
I bought a notebook a couple of days ago, with win7 installation on boot.
After Windows i installed Ubuntu 14.04. I want to try something new after all the years using Windows.

Unfortunately the notebook doesn't shut down properly using Ubuntu 14.04. (it's stuck at the orange dots), on Windows it works. I tried to install the newest drivers for the gpu (intel), but they are not available for 14.04 only for 14.10.

So i updated to 14.10 and now comes the newest of my problems:
After passing GRUB, im stuck on a black screen with '_' .

My first experience with Ubuntu is stereotypical. A stream of problems and no working OS.

I hope some of you guys can help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can choose another kernel at the beginning of the booting sequence, maybe your old 14.04 one.
Or you can run terminal/x-term etc., chroot to the directory (chroot /mnt (in case you have mounted your root filesystem there)) and install the old kernel, which should be sufficient in your case.
You can also install a new kernel from here:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Be sure to add a newer or older kernel, it sometimes doesn't work at all.
For example, you could download the kernel from here:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.18.12-vivid/

Or you can try any directory you desire. If you have AMD64 architecture, you can download the kernels with generic and amd64.

I don't have the necessary reputation to write it all for you. In directory, you have downloaded these kernels (be sure you are chrooted and that they are in the same location) run:
dpkg -i *.deb

I hope it works for you.

Comment: it would be the same as installing 14.04 again, wouldn't it?
then i'd have the old problems with the gpu drivers and could not shut down properly.

Comment: No. You'll change only the kernel, you don't have to worry about that :) You may experience some troubles with Nvidia drivers, when you have installed them, but I think it'll be OK :)